# Vi Mode in IPython: Issue with Bracket Deletion and Repeat Commands

Tags: ipython

I am using IPython with vi mode enabled, but I've encountered a couple of issues. Are these configuration problems, or has vi mode in IPython been implemented this way by design? Here are the specific issues I'm facing:

1. I can jump between opening and closing brackets using <kbd>%</kbd>. However, if I precede the <kbd>%</kbd> with <kbd>d</kbd> (to delete the brackets and their contents), the whole line is deleted.
2. Using <kbd>.</kbd> to repeat the last command simply doesn't do anything.
3. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> to increase number doesn't do anything.
4. Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> to decrease number doesn't do anything.

### My Configuration

- IPython Version: 8.19.0
- Python Version: 3.12.1
- iTerm2 Build 3.4.23
- OS: macOS 14.2.1 (Sonoma)

### Steps to Reproduce (<kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>)

- Configure ipython to use vi mode.
- start ipython.
- enter `a = [2, 3]` followed by <kbd>ESC</kbd>.
- move cursor to the first opening bracket, `[`.
- type <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd>.
- Observe: the whole line is deleted.

### Expected Behavior

After typing <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>%</kbd> with the cursor on the opening bracket `[` this part of the source should still be around:

```
a =
```

Instead, the whole line gets deleted.

### Steps to Reproduce (<kbd>.</kbd>)

- Configure ipython to use vi mode.
- start ipython.
- enter `a = [2, 3]` followed by <kbd>ESC</kbd>.
- type <kbd>.</kbd>.

### Expected Behavior

After typing <kbd>.</kbd>, the previously entered `a = [2, 3]` should be repeated such that we end up with `a = [2, 3]a = [2, 3]`.

Instead, nothing happens.

Comment: There is no "Vim mode" for IPython3, just "vi" mode. Note that Vim != vi != IPython3. Even vi had `%` so it's just an arbitrary subset of features being supported. The help is also vague (read: says nothing) about it. The way I see it, you can 1) try out, 2) rain bugs and feature requests on the IPython3 project, or 3) use Vim itself for editing Python code.

Comment: Thanks. To expand on my previous comment, from my experience vi modes usually mean `hjkl` navigation and the dev's favorite two or three commands. (On the other hand: where would you draw the line?) I've come to expect little of such modes. I cannot provide a definitive answer but I'd lean towards "by design" where design means the bare minimum needed to stick a "vi" label on it. I'll better stop the rant now.